# Code inside of class outside of methods vs code outside class

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here are two snippets of code:

Code 1:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
class Foo:
    with open('myfile.json') as f:
        bar = json.loads(f)
    del f

    def __init__(self):
        print('Constructor')

# end of file
```

Code 2:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Constructor')

with open('myfile.json') as f:
    Foo.bar = json.loads(f)
del f

# end of file
```

Is there any difference between these two codes? If not, which one is to be preferred?

Comment: @Matiiss: The name will not get garbage collected. Names don't get garbage collected, objects do, and without the `del f`, the file object is still reachable and ineligible for reclamation.

Answer (score 3):

Code 1: The outside-of-method code gets run once at the time of the definition of the class.

Code 2: The outside-of-method-and-class code gets run once during module import.

Since class definition happens at module import, the outcome should be exactly the same:

In either variation you end up with a class `Foo` whose class variable `bar` is set to the output of `json.loads(f)`.

What's preferred? That's ultimately a matter of taste, isn't it? Code 1 emphasizes that this json and `bar` business belongs to the class. Code 2 emphasizes that our module does something special upon import. Sometimes that's an important point to make.

Answer (score 1):

Both snippets achieve more or less the same thing, with the difference in cleanliness. In the first snippet, when reading this piece of code, you already know that the bar contains the contents of a file. In the second snippet, however, you don't know that the class has a variable `bar` until you see the end of a file.

Comment: "First and foremost - since you are using context manager with, you do not have to delete f at the end, the garbage collector will take care of it." - not true. The `with` will take care of *closing* the file, but it won't unbind the `f` name, and the garbage collector will not collect the file object.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica you are right, I misunderstood `with` then. I have updated my answer.